# Fatal error: Uncaught no such id - API response(PHP)

Tags: php, api

I am trying to get all infos from an API, where I dont know every single ID the API can get me. So basically I am calling for 1 info after another while I increase the ID:

```
<?php

$i = 0;
while ($i < 1000)
{
    if ($api->traits()->get($i) == "Uncaught no such id")
    {
        echo "do something";
        $i++;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "do something else";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

My error code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught no such id (status: 404; url:....)

Is there a way that the program doesn't stop on a Fatal error? Or that it reboot the script on fatal error with one higher ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're seeing an Uncaught [Exception](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). See the `catch` block? That's what it means by "uncaught".

Try this:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i < 1000)
{
    try
    {
        $trait = $api->traits()->get($i);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $ex->getMessage();
        echo "(do something else)";

        $i++;
        continue;
    }


    echo "found trait " . $trait;
    $i++;
}
```

Also, this is probably a situation where you should use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    try
    {
        $trait = $api->traits()->get($i);
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $ex->getMessage();
        echo "(do something else)";

        continue;
    }


    echo "found trait " . $trait;
}
```

I should also add that `Exception` is the very base type or class of exception, and APIs and libraries will typically throw a more specific type of exception.

```
catch (Exception $ex) { ... }
```

will catch any type of exception, but

```
catch (HttpConnectionException $ex) { ... }
```

would only catch an Exception of type `HttpConnectionException`. This allows you to handle specific types of errors differently. You can use `get_class($ex)` to see what exact type of `Exception` the API is throwing if you like.

Comment: Wow, thank you sir. I am smiling right now. I didn´t think that it was possible and I was like "meh should I post this silly problem or not"

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you!  I also added a note at the bottom about catching specific types of exceptions rather than catching "all Exceptions"; but, the PHP documentation link in my original post explains that also.